# Folder acess denied wpf

Tags: wpf

I am opening a FileDialog, to let the user select an Audio file, in an MP3 file, and convert it to WAV, the error appears when I am trying to save the file in a new folder that I am creating

```
var dlg = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                DefaultExt = ".mp3",
                Filter = "Audio files (.mp3)|*.mp3"
            };

            var res = dlg.ShowDialog();

            if (res! == true)
            {
                var projectPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())?.Parent?.Parent?.FullName;
                var FoderName = Path.Combine(projectPath!, "Audios");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(FoderName);

                using (var mp3 = new Mp3FileReader(dlg.FileName))
                {
                    using (var ws = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(mp3))
                    {
                        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(FoderName, was) // Error 
                        System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 
                      'C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX' is denied.'

                    }

                }
```

Thanks

Comment: Appdata was invented at the time ms realised allowing programs to write to where they were installed was a buge security risk. That was when win 7 came out. You're like 12 years too late for writing where programs are.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30915.c-local-files.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside some folders including "Program Files", an app usually has no permission to write a file. Therefore, it is recommended to use a folder dedicated for a specific purpose and made available for apps (you can get path to "Music" by `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic)`.

In general, an app must expect `UnauthorizedAccessException` when attempting to write a file and prepare a fallback for the case of that exception.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I was hoping, to save it in the new folder, Anyway thank you so much. Some people here they are very rude, and just mark your question as negative for no reason. I always say if you don't like my question do not read it.